Aggregate Demand and Aggregate Supply
Suppose the economy is at full employment and aggregate demand falls. Show the effects on output and prices in the short-run. Also, show how the Keynesian aggregate supply adjusts over time to bring the economy to the long-run equilibrium. I don't know what this means and also if you could, please help me with the graph. How do we represent the answer graphically?

Hi: Hopefully someone else can and  will provide more details but you should be reading about the phillips curve. That's fundamental to your question in case the professor hasn't explicitly mentioned it. There are so many papers on the phillips curve that I wouldn't know how to choose what to link to.
